# Incorrect height with scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to count the number of pixels user has scrolled, but the total than scrollTop shows is different from the sum of the different window's height defined.

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="slide slide1">
</div>
<div class="slide slide2">
</div>
<div class="slide slide3">
</div>
<div class="slide slide4">
</div>
<div class="slide slide5">
</div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.slide1 {
    background: red;
}

.slide2 {
    background: blue;
}

.slide3 {
    background: yellow;
}

.slide4 {
    background: green;
}

.slide5 {
    background: gray;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(window).scrollTop($(document).height());

        $('h2').text($(window).height() + 'px');
        $('h1').text($(document).scrollTop() + 'px');

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            $('h1').text( $(this).scrollTop() + 'px');
        });
});
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/w9bxhsvj/2/

For example, if the window height is 611px, and there are 5 divs with height 100%, the *scrollTop* value should be 3055px, but it shows 2452px. ¿What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a padding/margin problem.

apply `padding:0; margin:0;` to `html, body, h1, h2`
it will solve your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/w9bxhsvj/4/

Comment: It's seems the first one doesn't count.

Comment: count start at 0, scroll on top give 0.

Comment: Use `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()`